# Why is $\cos(x)dx$ a differential form

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, terminology, differential

I am trying to understand the concept of the differential

A differential $d$ is a map that sends functions to 1-forms

A preliminary example is

$$d\sin(x) = \cos(x) dx$$

So the operator $d$ sends a function $\sin(x)$ to a differential form $\cos(x)dx$

My question is that while $dx$ is obviously a differential form, but $\cos(x)$ is just a function.

What makes a function multiplying a differential form a differential form? i.e why would $\cos(x)dx$ be a differential form when the only identifiable differential form is the quantity $dx$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differential forms can be added, multiplied by scalars, and given a product, namely the wedge product. Let $E^k (M)$ denote the set of all smooth $k$-forms on $M$, a manifold.

> **Proposition**: $E^0 (M)$, the set of all smooth 0-forms, can be identified with $C^\infty (M)$.

Forms can be given a multiplication, namely the wedge product. In your case, you have $\cos (x) \in E^0 (M)$ and $dx \in E^1 (M)$. Writing $\cos (x) dx$ is actually shorthand for writing $\cos (x) \wedge dx \in E^{0 + 1} (M)$ and hence is a 1-form.

Comment: Hi! This looks a bit different than the way my book puts it -- so would you say that $2\,dx$ is really $2 \wedge dx$?

Comment: $E^* (M)$ can be multiplied by scalars as well, such as $2$.

Comment: @EliRose You can certainly consider $2$ to be a function here if that helps.  It's just the function that maps every point to the number $2$.

Comment: @T.S.L. Hi maybe I am not understanding something but on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function , the properties of $d$ is that $d(af+bg) = adf + bdg$, where $a,b$ are constants. So you mean we can replace say $a$ by $\cos(x)$ and everything still holds?

Comment: @FemaleTank The rule you want to use is [$d(\alpha \wedge \beta) = d\alpha \wedge \beta + (-1)^p(\alpha \wedge d\beta)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative) where $\alpha$ is a $p$-form ($\cos(x)$ is a $0$-form).  Note that $d^2\omega = 0$ for all $\omega$ is one of the terms is zero in this case.

Comment: @FemaleTank: Note that the majority of that Wikipedia article defines "differential" in a way unrelated to differential forms. Down in "other approaches" it mentions that one can think of $d$ as an exterior derivative, but the main article does not take that perspective.

Answer (score 1):

(Just learning all this myself, so if something seems wrong it probably is.) A $k$-form is a function that takes $k$ vectors and returns a scalar.

$$\cos(x)\,dx$$

is a $1$-form -- its value evaluated on the vector $(a, b, c)$ is

$$a\cdot\cos(a)$$

A one-form, let's say on $\mathbb{R}^3$:

$$f_1(x, y, z)\,dx + f_2(x, y, z)\,dy + f_3(x, y, z)\,dz$$

is called *differential* if $f_1, f_2, f_3$ are all differentiable. So $\cos(x)\,dx$ is a differential form.

It's true that $dx$ by itself is a differential form, and it's true that $\cos(x)\,dx$ is also a differential form. It just has a scalar in front of it.

Comment: A $1$-form is actually something like a **covector field**.  That means that it attaches a covector to each point on a manifold.  So it is evaluated at a pair $v_p = (p,\vec v)$ where $p$ is a point on your manifold and $\vec v$ is a vector in the tangent space at $p$.  So when you go to evaluate $\cos(x)dx$ you need both the point and the tangent vector.  A simple example: Say you have $p=(1,2,3)$ and $\vec v = (4,5,6)$, then $(\cos(x)dx)(v_p) = \cos(1)dx(4,5,6) = \cos(1)\cdot 4\ne \cos(1)\cdot 1$ or $\cos(4)cdot 4$.